# How to remove left side panel on component page?

Tags: joomla-extensions, joomla1.6, joomla-template

I am using Joomla 1.6.5 with default theme "Beez2 - Default". I have created a top menu item with type as external link which has link 'index.php?option=com_sample'. When i click on this menu item i can see the output of the component 'sample'.

But on the left side there are few menus like User Menu, About Joomla, This Site. I want to remove that whole vertical panel so that i can use more space for my sample component.

I tried to search in administrator panel and on google but cant find anything to remove left panel.
How can i remove that panel? what code should i write in sample component file to make it not display the left panel..

Please guide me.... thanks in advance.!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the menu not to appear when your component is the one used. Remove the show in all pages setting in the menu module.